# Pipe operation dplyr R with object returned a list

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I am trying to calculate concordance value (using epiR package) between measured and predicted for each group with a dplyr pipe operation. My example code is below

```
measured <- c(23, 20, 24, 26, 23, 46, 47, 45, 47, 46, 67, 68, 64, 63, 63)
predicted <- c(21, 19, 25, 23, 25, 48, 45, 46, 48, 46, 67, 68, 64, 63, 63)
gdata <- cbind(replicate, measured, predicted)
gdata <- as.data.frame(gdata)
head(gdata)
gdata$replicate <- as.factor(gdata$replicate)
test <- gdata %>% 
group_by(replicate) %>%
mutate(tt <- epiR::epi.ccc(gdata$measured, gdata$predicted))
```

What I want is to extract the tt$rho$est value that returns within the list for each group in this case replicate. However, I am getting an error. It works outside the pipe operation using below code. Any help is appreciated.

```
tt <- epi.ccc(bootdata$CalCut_DRY, bootdata$Predicted)   
tt$rho.c$est
```

Comment: It would be very helpful to provide a couple of groups of the data in `gdata` so that potential answerers can test what you are trying to do. Ideally showing your expected output along with the example data. See here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example - for some tips on how to share your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(dplyr)

gdata %>% 
 group_by(replicate) %>%
 mutate(tt = epiR::epi.ccc(measured, predicted)$rho.c$est)
```

If the `rho.c$est` value is same for the group then you probably can use `summarise` instead of `mutate`.